# Create HorizontalScrollView moving on swipe gestures

Tags: android, swipe, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have no idea how to implement a HorizontalScrollView that scrolls on swipes. And it should scroll to specific position. The positions are one the picture. The first one is how it appears from the beginning. Then when you swipe right, the scrll view slides to the beginning and number appears. Then when you swipe left you come back to the first position. And after swipe left from the first position, scroll view scrolls to the end and shows sharing options. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be implemented with ViewPager rather than Horizontal ScrollView.
Take a look to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: Thanks, but is that possible, not to change all view on swipe?